# Is the set S closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S = \{(x_1,x_2):(x_1-1)^2+x_2^2=1 \}$

I have to show that S is closed. I searched a lot about how to prove that a set is closed but was not able to understand much. To be more specific, I did not get the intuitive grasp of the method that uses sequences to show that a set is closed. In general, how do we show that sets of similar definition as the one defined above are closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1-1)^2+x_2^{\,2}$, then $f$ is continuous. Since $\{1\}$ is closed subset of $\Bbb R$, it follows that $S$ is closed, since $S$ is equal to $f^{-1}\big(\{1\}\big)$.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to show such algebraically defined sets to be closed is to use a function which is continuous.

Define $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ by $f(x,y)= (x-1)^2 +y^2$. $f$ is continuous as $\Bbb R$ is a topological ring.

And $S=f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ is closed as the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous map.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(a_n,b_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $S$. Let $(a,b)$ be the limit i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = b$.

Then $(a_n-1)^2 + b_n^2 = 1$ and the function $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+y^2$ is continuous, thus
$1 = \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n-1)^2 + b_n^2 = (a-1)^2+b^2$ which shows that $(a,b)\in S$.
We have shown that for any convergent sequence in $S$ the limit is also contained in $S$, thus $S$ is closed.